# Working out the new price from a %

Tags: php

I have tried to do this myself,  it seems fairly simple i must be over complicating it, i have the following code:

```
// get the % we make
$row = DB::getInstance()->selectValues('SELECT * FROM `profit`');  
$per = $row['profit_percentage'];
$pro = $per * 100 - ((str_replace("$", " ", trim($offer->children('campinfo', true)->amount) / 100)));
```

The value of `$per = 60` this value `$offer->children('campinfo', true)->amount` can contain any value like: `0.55` or `25.34` what i'm trying to do is deduct 60 (the percentage) off the value of `$offer->children('campinfo', true)->amount`

I'm going round in circles

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to deduct 60%, i.e. you want 40% of the original value? `originalValue * 0.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to simple math:
Giving a 60% discount is the same as only charging 40%.
So all you have to do is calculate `$price * 0.4`.

Pro tipp: Don't store your percentage as {0..100}, but as {0..1}. That way you can rewrite your code as `(1 - $per) * $price`!